# CheckingButton Background Resource Id android

Tags: java, android, android-button

I have a button

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setBakgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
```

If I want to check which background resource button has, is it possible to do so? how.

For example :

```
if (button.getResourceId()==R.drawable.icon)
```

do something with code...

**UPDATE: THE CONDITION IS FALSE I WANT IT TO BE TRUE THE IMAGES DO NOT MATCH**

```
vi.findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
 
            v.findViewById(R.id.button1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.boutton_off);
            
            Drawable aImg = (Drawable)v.findViewById(R.id.button1).getBackground();
            Drawable bImg = v.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boutton_off);
            
            if(aImg==bImg){
                
                System.out.println("On");

            }else 
                System.out.println("off");

            
            
            //main.popMessage(position);
            
            
        }
        
    });
```

Comment: that's not how it works. A/ you are comparing different instances, so aImg != bImg no matter what. B/ knowing if your button is on or off is a Data property, not someting you pull from the UI, which is Display. You are supposed to know which statt your buttons are in.

Comment: is there a way to check that a specific button has been pressed ? this button is in a list and have the same id. so forget the id

Comment: you can keep a reference to the button. if it is in a list, you can keep a list of the checked items. if it actually is in a listview, listview handles that for you, see the doc for details.

Comment: where can i find this doc

Comment: http://developer.android.com

Answer (score 10):

If you are setting multiple drawable backgrounds for a button then you check it as follows

```
    if(button.getBackground().getConstantState()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.name1).getConstantState())
{
//Your code
}
else if(button.getBackground().getConstantState()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.name2).getConstantState())
{
//Your code
}
else
{
//Your code
}
```

You can use `button.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.name1).getConstantState())` if above code doesn't work

Comment: **getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.example)** is **deprecated** in latest sdk. Instead use this **ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.example))**

Comment: @Dasser Basyouni can you provide more info like OS version, how you are implementing etc. I'll have a lookout. Tested this on my 4.4 KK & 7.1 N roms. Working fine for me.

Comment: I have tested it on 5.1.1 Huawei 7D-501 Beta B110 ROM, and I have implemented it exactly like your first comment, and to be more sure of my result I make it a Logcat and it displays 2 different outputs for the same drawable: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState@1011644c And android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable$RippleState@2bf0c95

Comment: Okay I'll check and get back

Comment: Meanwhile try to use deprecated method and check. I had used that one.

Comment: also the same I have tried it before, also == and .equal(), I don't know whats wrong

Comment: Tested with different versions of Android OS from JB 4.1 to N 7.1.2. The above method fails to work in all LP 5.x versions. Other versions work fine. Trying to find a workaround.....

Answer (score 5):

It seems not to be possible. The ressource is resolved to a Drawable and thats all you can get back in the standard functionality. Maybe there is a way to resolve the drawable back to the id in another way, but this functionality is not impleneted in the buttonclass.

If you need an easy access to that resourceId and you are setting the ressource from code you can write your ButtonClass implementing the Android Button and overload/create the setBackgroundResource to save the id in an additional field you can then access.
This, of course, doesn't work, if the button gets his BackgroundRessource not due a function call from your side.

Here some code.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyButton extends Button {
    private int bgId;

    public MyButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
    @Override
    public void setBackgroundResource(int resId) {
        super.setBackgroundResource(resId);
        bgId = resId;   
    }

    public int getBackgroundId() {
        return bgId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i solved this problem by using hashmap. after a lot of wasting time of searching about how to get background resources. when i want to set background resources but also i don't want to lose what i set, i made something like that :

```
HashMap<Button,Integer> hashMap;
myButton.setBackgroundResources(R.drawable.my_image);
hashMap.put(myButton,R.drawable.my_image);
```

now if do you want to compare that image with another one :

```
if(hashMap.get(myButton)==R.drawable.my_image)
{
 myButton.setBackgroundResources(R.drawable.another_image);
 hashMap.put(myButton,R.drawable.another_image);
}
```

**Remember: if did you put another resource with existing key ,the value will be overwritten**,
*dont forget to initialize hashmap before it's being used*
that's all hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

as @Nihal has answered is wonderful, however getResources() has now been depricated, in which case you can go straight to getDrawable()

FOR JAVA:

```
    if(button.getBackground().getConstantState()==getDrawable(R.drawable.name1).getConstantState())
{
//Your code
}
else if(button.getBackground().getConstantState()==getDrawable(R.drawable.name2).getConstantState())
{
//Your code
}
else
{
//Your code
}
```

FOR KOTLIN

```
   if(button.background.constantState==getDrawable(R.drawable.name1)?.getConstantState){
//Your code
}
else if(button.background.constantState==getDrawable(R.drawable.name2)?.getConstantState){
//Your code
}
else
{
//Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think getBackground() is what you are looking for. It returns a drawable, so you can check it like this:

```
Button myButton = ...;
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable. ... ); //the one you are looking for
if(myButton.getBackground().equals(myDrawable)){
....
}
```

Comment: I think the problem might be with "==", try "equals" instead. And also, I think v.getResources() won't work this time, as it returns the resources related to the view, not the context. Try context.getResources() instead.

Comment: can you provide me with a sample please

Comment: I guess, you are doing all this in an activity (e.g. MainActivity), so use MainActivity.this.getResources.getDrawable(R.drawable.boutton_off); and the if statement shell be like if(aImg.equals(bImg))

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.getTag();

if (hashMap.get(imageView) == R.drawable.hover) {
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hover1);
    imageView.setTag(imageView);
    hashMap.put(imageView, R.drawable.hover1);
} else {
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hover);
    imageView.setTag(imageView);
    hashMap.put(imageView, R.drawable.hover);
}
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this..
1.Whatever background you set for your button also set this background as an Id of button.Means `button.setId(R.drawable.image);`

2.Then check condition..

```
int temp = button.getId();
    if(temp == R.drawable.image){
    //Do something...
    }
```

Hope it helps you...

Comment: so wrong. you are comparing an id from a button to the value of a drawable identifier ? never going to be equal, or at least not in any case you'd want it to.

Comment: It works fine for me to change the background of button..@njzk2

Comment: it is a very bad practice. drawables and ids are different things and are not supposed to be mixed up. You can declare your own ids (without adding @+id in the layout) using the res/values/ids.xml file, and use these, but don't use the drawable values for ids. They represent different things

Answer (score -1):

```
Drawable aImg = (Drawable)done.getBackground();
Drawable bImg = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
if(aImg==bImg){

}
```